# Simple linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

My book (Friedberg) doesn't directly address this question but is it true that if the matrix representation of a linear operator $T$ in a basis $\beta$ is diagonal then the basis consists of eigenvectors of $T$? I think Theorem 5.1 states that the converse of my question is true. However if when trying to find $[T]_\beta$ a vector of $\beta$ returns a multiple of itself under $T$, that vector would have to be an eigenvector of $T$ right? That's my line of thinking. Also, what can be said if $[T]_\beta$ is anti-diagonal? Would $\beta$ consist of eigenvectors of $T$ in that case? I'm thinking no. While the off diagonal basis vectors are multiples of a basis vector, that basis vector is not itself (confusing wording I hope I'm understood). Again, I don't see this addressed in Chapter 5.1 explicitly.

Comment: Yes and no. ${}$

Comment: So yes to if $[T]_\beta$ is diagonal then $\beta$ consists of eigenvectors of $T$, and no to if $[T]_\beta$ is anti-diagonal then $\beta$ consists of eigenvectors of $T$?

Comment: @jesusbourne yes!

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate it.

Comment: The answer to the first question should be obvious if you recall that the columns of the matrix are the images of the basis vectors.